# Switching from 32-bit to 64 bit causes exit for a leap motion listener on java

Tags: java, eclipse, leap-motion

After taking a java program (with Eclipse IDE) to use leap motion listener from a 32-bit windows to a 64-bit windows, the program appears to be running properly.

The problem is that now the connection to the controller is initialized, connected then immediately exits without me doing anything.

I tried putting my hand over the controller and got this error

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fee8b4a975, pid=10516, >tid=23920
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51->b16)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode windows->amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [Leap.dll+0x2a975]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client >versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   M:\Leapduino\Leapduino_test\hs_err_pid10516.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

I tried to change to an older version of java, but no luck either.

Any ideas how it can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from Joe_Ward from Team Leap Motion:

https://community.leapmotion.com/t/leap-crash-java-windows/703?u=sgerish